# Java Swing bug/error created by IntelliJ IDEA Windowbuilder

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA 15 and create this window.
Its a Java swing application.

1. my GUI shows this bug. I dont know why. I tried to repaint / revalidate / validte but nothing helps me.

[image: GUI BUG]

if I change the Mouseposition the bug follow

[image]
2. why is my background black? And here you can see the bug.

Help me pls

Main method to launch

```
public class Launch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        WebLookAndFeel.install();
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setUndecorated(true);
        main.setVisible(true);
        main.pack();
    }
}
```

And this is my constructor

```
public Main() throws URISyntaxException {
    setRealFeel();
    setContentPane(mainPanel);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setLocation(((dim.width / 2) - 200), ((dim.height / 2) - 150));
    ComponentResizer cr = new ComponentResizer();
    cr.registerComponent(this);
    cr.setSnapSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
    cr.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    mainMenu.setVisible(false);
    loadingPanel.setVisible(false);
    this.mainFrame = this;
    closeLabel.setIcon(closeImage);
    closeLabel.setText("");
    miniLabel.setIcon(minimizeImage);
    miniLabel.setText("");
    maxSizeLabel.setIcon(maximizeImage);
    maxSizeLabel.setText("");
    maxSizeLabel.setVisible(false);
    this.checkBoxMap = new HashMap<String, JCheckBox>();
    this.calendarMap = new HashMap<String, Calendar>();

    this.content.setLayout(new CardLayout());
    this.content.add("login", loginPanel);
    this.content.add("index", indexPanel);
    this.cardLayout = (CardLayout) content.getLayout();

    this.indexPanel.setLayout(new CardLayout());
    this.indexPanel.add("calendar", calendarPanel);
    this.indexPanel.add("customer", customerPanel);
    this.indexPanel.add("employee", employeePanel);
    this.indexCardLayout = (CardLayout) indexPanel.getLayout();


    titlePanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            // Get x,y and store them
            pX = me.getX();
            pY = me.getY();

        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
            setLocation(getLocation().x + me.getX() - pX,
                    getLocation().y + me.getY() - pY);
        }
    });

    titlePanel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
            setLocation(getLocation().x + me.getX() - pX,
                    getLocation().y + me.getY() - pY);
        }
    });

    /*Image Hover*/
    closeLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseClicked(e);
            Close close = new Close();
            close.setVisible(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseEntered(e);
            closeLabel.setIcon(closeImageHover);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseExited(e);
            closeLabel.setIcon(closeImage);
            repaint();
        }
    });

    miniLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseClicked(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseEntered(e);
            miniLabel.setIcon(minimizeImageHover);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseExited(e);
            miniLabel.setIcon(minimizeImage);
            repaint();
        }
    });

    maxSizeLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseClicked(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseEntered(e);
            maxSizeLabel.setIcon(maximizeImageHover);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseExited(e);
            maxSizeLabel.setIcon(maximizeImage);
            repaint();
        }
    });

    impactImage.setIcon(loginImage);
    btnLink.setText("Impact WebDesign");
    btnLink.addActionListener(new OpenUrlAction());

    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            (new Thread(new Login(textField1.getText(), passwordField1.getPassword(), mainFrame))).start();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Without knowing anything about your code, we can't help you. Is this a Java Swing application? Is it a JavaFX application? Or something else?

Comment: Its a Java swing Application

Comment: And what does your code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it... it's a graphic bug. I test it on my Laptop and there is all fine...

Thanks